# Adjusting classification thresholds based on test set predictions

Tags: classification, cross-validation, precision-recall

I have a binary classifier that was trained using k-fold cross validation. I then use the model to get predictions on an unseen (held out) test data set. For my specific application, I would like a certain recall value at the expense of a lower precision by varying the probability threshold - e.g. if the predicted probability is above 41%, predict 1, else 0 (rather than the default 50%).

Is it ok to choose this probability threshold **based on the predicted probabilities of the test set?** Or would this be considered biasing the model and not generalizing to new data? If the latter, how could I choose a probability threshold that achieves my desired recall score (using the training data perhaps)?

Comment: You should cross validate the threshold.  The test set should only be used to obtain estimates of out of sample predictions.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the threshold on any set of hold out data you'd like, but that set of data then indeed incurs an optimistic bias about your performance metrics. Generally you want to hold out either a third validation set (not recommended for smaller datasets, due to high estimation variance), or use some nested cross-validation/bootstrapping technique to work out the proper threshold.